# items are cramped on top of each other when using angular-masonry directive to create layout

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Am using angular in this simple search results page and instead of adding jquery masonry for layout and deal with timing issues I decided to give this directive a try since it plays nicely with the ng-repeat.

Unfortunately when I have a large dataset and the ng-repeat takes a second or two, the page gets all screw up and all items render on top of each other. Someone claimed that it has something to do with the last element in the ng-repeat not being loaded by the time the layout is created through the plugin.

Someone else recommended a timeout to create a delay, this option works but the user can see the layout being built, which is not the best solution.

Anyone out there that has use this directive to create a masonry layout with a large dataset?